# PyParsing's searchString with StringStart() and StringEnd()

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to make the following tests pass:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, StringStart, StringEnd
import pytest

def get_square_feet(string):
    area = Word(nums+",")("area").setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: [int(t[0].replace(',', ''))])
    expression = StringStart() + area + "sqft" + StringEnd()
    return expression.parseString(string).get("area")

def test_get_square_feet():
    assert get_square_feet("800 sqft") == 800
    assert get_square_feet("9,000 sqft") == 9000

def test_get_square_feet_with_prefix():
    assert get_square_feet("size: 12,000 sqft") is None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

However, the second tests fails because it leads to a `ParseError`. Instead, I'd like use `searchString`, but if I replace `parseString` by `searchString` in the `get_square_feet` function I also get an error because the function returns `None`. Can someone point out to me what is wrong here?

Comment: `searchString` (and `scanString` both) accommodate the 'size: ' fragment at the beginning of the string that you don't want to allow.

Comment: I doubt that I understand what you're trying to do. Is it possible that you could use a `try ... except` with a parsing error as the exception condition for the `assert`?

Comment: Actually, @BillBell, `searchString` and `scanString` *won't* accommodate the 'size:' fragment because `expression` requires that the integer value must immediately follow `StringStart`. @KurtPeek, your use of `StringStart` as part of the expression is what is messing up your use of `searchString`/`scanString`.

Comment: A blunder! I meant to say that `searchString` would accommodate the 'size:' thing without those. I had become utterly confused. @PaulMcG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corresponding code using pyparsing, catching the ParseException:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, StringStart, StringEnd, ParseException

def get_square_feet(string):
    area = Word(nums+",")("area").setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: [int(t[0].replace(',', ''))])
    expression = StringStart() + area + "sqft" + StringEnd()
    try:
        return expression.parseString(string).get("area")
    except ParseException:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses [parsy](http://parsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which is like pyparsing in many ways but with a nicer interface and implementation IMO.

```
from parsy import regex

def get_square_feet(s):
    area = regex(r'[0-9,]+').map(lambda s: int(s.replace(',', '')))
    return (area << string(" sqft") | regex('.*').result(None)).parse(s)
```

Here we use the `|` combinator to fallback to a regex that accepts anything, but then produces `None` as required. You could also implement it by catching the `ParseError` exception and returning `None` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of `get_square_feet` which passes the tests using regular expressions:

```
def get_square_feet(string):
    match = re.match(r'^([\d,]+) sqft$', string)
    return int(match.groups()[0].replace(',', '')) if match else None
```

In principle, PyParsing should be easier to use than regular expressions, so I'm still interested in a solution using PyParsing.

Comment: The issue isn't so much that pyparsing is broken, as that its API is not the same as re. In `re.match`, a failure to match just returns None. In pyparsing, a failure to match raises a ParseException. If you change your implementation of `get_square_feet` to catch that exception using Python `try..except`, and in the event of an exception to return None, then that should give you what you want for handling the error case.